# LaTeX figure drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks

[image]

How to draw this figure in LaTeX?

I am new to LaTeX figure drawing. Here I see two round headed rectangles and two circles. Also I am eager to know that can I draw this in Overleaf?

Answer (score 12):

One out of many possibilities.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=2pt}]
\node[rounded rectangle,draw,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=4mm,rotate=20](A) at (0,0){};
\node[rounded rectangle,draw,minimum width=3cm,minimum
height=4mm,rotate=80,anchor=west](B) 
at ([xshift=-1mm]A.south east){};
\node[bullet,shift={(200:2mm)}] at (A.east){};
\node[bullet,shift={(20:2mm)}] at (A.west){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The figure reminds me of a toy called "Metallbaukasten" (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallbaukasten). It would be interesting if there is a package for this.

Comment: @Stefan I am not aware of such a package. (And I guess kids will prefer the real thing anyway. ;-)

Comment: I had thought of the usage for simulation purposes.

Answer (score 11):

Just another solution.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill circle(2pt) coordinate(a) ++(20:2cm) circle(2pt) coordinate(b); 
\draw (a)++(110:2mm) arc (110:290:2mm)--++(20:2cm) arc (-70:110:2mm)--cycle;
\draw (b)++(170:2mm) arc (170:350:2mm)--++(80:2cm) arc (-10:170:2mm)--cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(4,5)
\pnodes(0,0){A}(3,1){B}(3.5,4){C}\psdots[dotscale=3](A)(B)
\ncbox[linearc=0.4,nodesep=4mm]{A}{B}
\ncbox[linearc=0.4,nodesep=4mm]{C}{B}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another option:  this one is in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) using the `mplib` package, so you need to use `lualatex` to compile it.  In Overleaf, click on "Menu" at the top left and choose "LuaLaTeX" as the compiler.

[image: A drawing of some semaphore arms.]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    vardef arm(expr extent, radius, mark_start, mark_end) =
        save P, A; 
        picture P; path A;
        A = halfcircle scaled 2 radius rotated 90 
         -- halfcircle scaled 2 radius rotated -90 shifted (extent, 0)
         -- cycle;
        P = image(draw A;
            if mark_start > 0:
                fill fullcircle scaled 2 mark_start;
            fi
            if mark_end > 0:
                fill fullcircle scaled 2 mark_end shifted (extent, 0);
            fi
        ); P
    enddef;
    draw arm(200, 16, 0, 6) rotated 200;
    draw arm(200, 16, 6, 0) rotated 60;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```